# Send Variable values from QDialog to QMainwindow function

Tags: c++, qt, qdialog

My UI MainWindow has a QListWidget and , upon clicking of its items ,a corresponding QDialog box must pop up , which prompts the user to enter some values in QDialog box, The values entered into line_edits of QDialog box must stored into a QString variable and this variable should be accessed/used in a function of MainWindow,

for Example: I have a QListWidget, with 3 items "New York","Glasgow","Mumbai", and when i double click item named "New York", a pop-up shows up asking me this
[image]

and after i enter 3 and Hilton , the item in QListWidget which was initially "New York" must be changed to
"New York -3 , The safehouse is in Hilton"
my code for MainWindow.cpp is

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <QtCore>
#include <QtGui>
#include <sstream>
#include <QtWidgets/qmessagebox.h>
#include <QtWidgets/qlistwidget.h>

using namespace std;

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget* parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->My_listwidget->addItem("New York");
    ui->My_listwidget->addItem("Glasgow");
    ui->My_listwidget->addItem("Mumbai");
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::on_My_listwidget_itemDoubleClicked(QListWidgetItem* item)
{
    QString test = item->text();
    std::string test_s = test.toStdString();

    if (test_s.find("New York") != std::string::npos) // check if item contains text "New York"
    {
        WinApp winApp;
        winApp.setModal(true);   //Displaying the window here
        winApp.exec();
    }
    
    if (test_s.find("Glasgow") != std::string::npos) 
    {
    // show another dialog box asking some questions
    }
    if (test_s.find("Mumbai") != std::string::npos) 
    {
    // show another dialog box asking some questions
    }
}
```

My code for mainwindow.h

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QtWidgets/QMainWindow>
#include "ExecutionContext.h"
#include <QtWidgets/qlistwidget.h>
//#include "secdialog.h"
#include <qregexp.h>

QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE
namespace Ui { class MainWindow; }
QT_END_NAMESPACE

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{

    Q_OBJECT                      //Used to handle events

public:
    MainWindow(QWidget* parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();                    //Destructor used to free resources

private slots:

    void on_xml_scripts_textbox_itemDoubleClicked(QListWidgetItem* item);

    Ui::MainWindow* ui; // pointing to UI class

private:

};
#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

my code for WinApp.h , winapp is the name of my dialog

```
#include <QtWidgets/qdialog.h>
#include "ui_WinApp.h"

class WinApp : public QDialog, public Ui::WinApp
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    WinApp(QWidget *parent = Q_NULLPTR);
    ~WinApp();

private slots:

private:
    Ui::WinApp ui;
};
```

WinApp.cpp

```
#include "WinApp.h"

WinApp::WinApp(QWidget *parent)
    : QDialog(parent)
{
    ui.setupUi(this);
}

WinApp::~WinApp()
{
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to add in the `WinApp` dialog class the test getter, it should be something like:

```cpp
QString getFavouriteHotel() const {
    return ui.<favourite-hotel-label>.text()
}
```

In the `MainWindow` after the line `winApp.exec();` I suggest adding an if to check if the user accepted or declined the dialog ([docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdialog.html#result)). If the user accepted the dialog then you can retrieve the text with the getters you just added.

Tips: avoid using `exec`, as said in the [docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdialog.html#exec) use the `open`

-- UPDATE -- QDialog accept --

Always check the [docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdialog.html#finished)

```cpp
connect(&WinApp, &QDialog::finished, this, [this](int result) {
    if(result == QDialog::Accepted){
       // do aswomness
       return
   }
});
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the answer, can you please show the if check ?

Comment: like when i click cancel, nothing should happen

Comment: Thanks for looking into this , i tried the code, but when i used this `connect(&WinApp, &QDialog::finished, this, [this](int result) `, it was giving me error "type name is not allowed " on &WinApp,

Comment: on my second try i did this, so i tried this `connect(winApp //using the object here, &QDialog::finished, this, [this](int result)`  but when i use this , `  connect(winApp &QDialog::finished, this, [this](int result) {
             if (result == QDialog::Accepted) {
                 item->setText(testo);
                 item->setData(CapitalRole, testo);
                 return
             }` i get an error near "item" saying "an enclosing-function local variable cannot be referenced in a lambda body unless it is in the capture list"

Comment: Check the [docs](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) please. Since `item` is not part of the class but function member you need to capture by reference:
change `[this](int result)` to `[&](int result)`

Answer (score 1):

Have the function initiating the `QDialog` object pass the `QString` argument in the constructor and override `accept()`.

```
#include <QtWidgets/qdialog.h>
#include "ui_WinApp.h"

class WinApp : public QDialog, public Ui::WinApp
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    WinApp(QString& stringToModify, QWidget *parent = Q_NULLPTR);
    ~WinApp();

private slots:
void accept() override;
private:
    Ui::WinApp ui;
};
```

and define the `acccept()` slot which will get the QString from lineEdit and update the stringToModify with it.

```
void WinApp::accept(){
//do stuff with QString
this->close();
}
```

Comment: Passing references like this could be dangerous. Also using a connect to get the accept event is unnecessary since [QDialog::accept](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdialog.html#accept) is virtual and could be overridden based on the user needs.

Comment: @AndreaRicchi what do you mean "could be dangerous" ?

Comment: sorry, I said that badly. I mean that is a bad practice; it's more C style passing a reference and modifying it in a class that doesn't own that member. It's against the idea of OOP.